# UWP - C# XAML - How to impose a constraint in a DependencyProperty?

Tags: c#, oop, uwp, uwp-xaml

In Object-Oriented-Programming, the objects manage their own properties with top authority, and communicates with others via their formal interfaces. That is the encapsulation principle. For plain properties there are the Getters/Setters.

An object can impose a constraint, for the allowed values in a setter. For example this class will not allow the Age property have a value less than 0, or more than 150:

```
Class person
{
    public string Name {get; set;}

    private int age;
    public int Age 
    {
        get => age;  
        set
        {
            if (value<0) throw new ArgumentException("no one can have negative age! you ape!");
            if (value>150) throw new ArgumentException("master Yoda's profile 
  should be loaded in the Galactic Empire database (currently developed by Mocrisoft)");
            age = value;
        } 
    }

}
```

Now, suppose Person class is a DependencyObject (it inherits from DependencyObject) and I want to expose a DepedencyProperty, and let this property of the object be slave of other object's property. So, Age property look like...:

```
    public int Age
    {
        get { return (int)GetValue(AgeProperty); }
        set { SetValue(AgeProperty, value); }
    }

    // Using a DependencyProperty as the backing store for Age.  This enables animation, styling, binding, etc...
    public static readonly DependencyProperty AgeProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Age", typeof(int), typeof(Person), new PropertyMetadata(0, callback));

    private static void callback(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // inspect changed triggered by other object ;
    }
```

With this approach, in the callback method I can inspect what is happening, I can inspect both, the old and new value. But with this I only can INSPECT the new value, but not limit or DISALLOW the new value.

How can I impose a restriction on the possible values the property can have?

Answer (score 0):

I don't use UWP but i think the term you are describing here is Validation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wpf/advanced/dependency-property-callbacks-and-validation

It appears there is an overload of .Register() that takes validators.  You might do something like this

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty AgeProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
    "Age",
    typeof(int),
    typeof(Person),
    new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(
        0,
        callback
    ),
    new ValidateValueCallback(IsValidAge)
);
```

and then

```
public static bool IsValidAge(object value)
{
    int v = (int)value;
    return (v > 0 && v < 150);
}
```

Comment: thanks for your reply. but that is for WPF. it seems the validation is not supported for UWP

Answer (score 0):

As you can see in the example, you can filter the data in Age's `Setter` and call the `SetValue()` method only if it meets the criteria.

```cs
public int Age
{
    get { return (int)GetValue(AgeProperty); }
    set 
    {
        if (value < 0)
        {
            // throw error or other things
        }
        else
        {
            SetValue(AgeProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

But if you want to adjust the controls that bind this property in XAML depending on the `Age`, you can consider using `IValueConverter`.

Here is the [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.ivalueconverter).

Best regards.